# do-while loop is infinite somehow and constantly appending file

Tags: c, append, jpeg, infinite-loop

I'm trying to recover deleted images from a SD card image. All seems ok until my do-while loop, specifically line 55 (I think is the problem). The loop is infinite and repeatedly appends to the last file it created. I try to sort-of brute force my way to get it working, with slight better results sometimes and worse results other times. Simply lost.

```
/**
 * recover.c
 *
 * Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
 */

 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #define BUFFER 512

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // jpeg signatures
    char sig1[] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0};
    char sig2[] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1};

    // buffer of 512 bytes
    char buffer[BUFFER];

    // counter for titles of jpgs
    int counter = 0;
    char title[8];

    // define and open card.raw
    FILE* card = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (card == NULL)
        {
            printf("Invalid file\n");
            return 1;
        }

    // read card.raw into buffer
    fread(&buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 512, card);

    while (!feof(card))
    {        
        // compare first 4 bytes of buffer and signatures
        if (memcmp(buffer, sig1, 4) == 0 || memcmp(buffer, sig2, 4 == 0))
        {
            // format title, open image, write img, then reload buffer
            do
            {
                sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", counter);
                FILE* img = fopen(title, "a");
                fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 512, img);
                fread(&buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 512, card);
                fclose(img);
            }
                // until buffer and a signature are equal
                while (memcmp(buffer, sig1, 4) != 0 && memcmp(buffer, sig2, 4) != 0);           

            // increase counter
            counter++;       
        }
        // if not jpg, read next block
        else
        fread(&buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 512, card);        
    }   

    // close card.raw
    fclose(card);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (memcmp(buffer, sig2, 4) != 0 && memcmp(buffer, sig2, 4) != 0);` should this be `sig1` and `sig2`?

Comment: I would like to add, it seems to recover images 000.jpg - 011.jpg seemingly perfect. On 012.jpg, however, the program hangs and never ends the loop and the file size of 012.jpg will climb as high as I let it go.

Comment: I guess that it never finds a next jpeg header when it's the last file and keeps reading other data from "card.raw"

Comment: card.raw is only 20.1 MB. If the code is right, does that mean the maximum file size of an image should be 20.1 MB?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you should try matching the end of a jpeg file instead of the beginning of the next one. Wikipedia says it should end with  0xFF, 0xD9.

Answer (score 0):

I made quite a lot of changes, but it's untested as I don't have the raw data. The main change is to the reading loop, which assumes each jpeg file is in consecutive sectors, and continues to read/write sectors until another signature is found, or the end of file.

Some minor changes are testing the number of bytes read instead of using `feof()`, and making use of `#define BUFFER 512` instead of hard coding `512`, and the bug mentioned by @RaphaelSantos.

You could also try to incorporate his later suggestion of testing the end of file.

```
/* recover.c    Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image. */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER 512

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // jpeg signatures
    unsigned char sig1[] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0};
    unsigned char sig2[] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe1};
    // buffer of 512 bytes
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER];
    // counter for titles of jpgs
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned bytes;
    char title[8];
    FILE *card, *img;

    // define and open card.raw
    if ((card = fopen("card.raw", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid input file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // read card.raw into buffer
    bytes = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER, card);
    while (bytes) {
        // compare first 4 bytes of buffer and signatures
        if (memcmp(buffer, sig1, 4) == 0 || memcmp(buffer, sig2, 4 == 0)) {
            // format title, open image, write img
            sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", counter);
            if ((img = fopen(title, "w")) == NULL) {
                printf("Invalid output file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            do {
                fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes, img);
                bytes = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER, card);
            } while (bytes && memcmp(buffer, sig1, 4) != 0 && memcmp(buffer, sig2, 4 != 0));
            fclose(img);
            counter++;
        }
        else
            bytes = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER, card);
    }
    fclose(card);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you have `bytes = fread(buffer,1 , BUFFER, card);` What data does the variable `bytes` have in it?

Comment: `bytes` is used both to correctly write the number of bytes read, and to check if the end of file was reached.

Answer (score 0):

Jpeg files start with two bytes 0xFF, 0xD8 and end with two bytes 0xFF, 0xD9. To be safe and easy to code (it will probably be slower), you should read bytes two by two and open a new file when you find the begin marker and close it when you find the end marker. Also, always check the return value of fread.
The following is untested, but should give you an idea of what I'm suggesting:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER 2

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // jpeg signatures
    unsigned char begin_pair [2] = {0xff, 0xd8};
    unsigned char end_pair [2] = {0xff, 0xd9};

    // buffer of 512 bytes
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER];

    // counter for titles of jpgs
    int counter = 0;
    char title[8] = {0};

    // define and open card.raw
    FILE* card = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (card == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // read card.raw into buffer

    FILE *img = NULL;
    size_t n = fread(&buffer, 1, BUFFER, card);
    while (n == BUFFER ){
        if (memcmp(buffer, begin_pair, 2) == 0) {
            if (img) {
                printf("%s not terminated properly\n", title);
                fclose(img);
                img = NULL;
            }
            snprintf(title, 8, "%03d.jpg", counter);
            img = fopen(title, "a");
            counter++;
            fwrite(&buffer, 1, BUFFER, img);
        }
        if (memcmp(buffer, end_pair, 2) == 0 && img) {
            fwrite(&buffer, 1, BUFFER, img);
            fclose(img);
            img = NULL;
        }
    }
    //test if there's an open image
    if (img) {
        fwrite(&buffer, 1, n, img);
        printf("%s not terminated properly\n", title);
        fclose(img);
    }
    // close card.raw
    fclose(card);
    return 0;
}
```